# Sum up rows according to specific values

Tags: r

That's my data frame

```
Colour = c("red",   "blue", "red",  "blue", "yellow",   "green",    "red",  "blue", "green",    "red",  "yellow",   "blue")
Volume  = c(46,46,57,57,57,57,99,99,99,111,111,122)
Cases   = c(7,2,4,2,3,5,1,2,3,2,4,1)
df = data.frame(Colour, Volume, Cases)
```

I want to sum up Cases if Colour is `"red"` OR `"blue"` but if Volume is identical.
Those colours which are not specified should be kept. If red and blue can't be summed
up because they differ in `Volume` then they should also be kept

The reult should look like that:

```
Colour = c("red_or_blue","red_or_blue","yellow","green","red_or_blue","green","red","yellow","blue")
Volume  = c(46,57,57,57,99,99,111,111,122)
Cases   = c(9,6,3,5,3,3,2,4,1)
df_agg = data.frame(Colour, Volume, Cases)
```

I've figured out a way where I create a further column which assigns an `"red_or_blue"` to the row with red or blue and an x for the remaining rows. I then used aggregate:

```
df$test = ifelse(df$Colour %in% c("red", "blue"),"red_or_blue","x")
df_agg = aggregate(df$Cases, list(df$Volume, df$test), sum)
```

It works but i found this a bit cumbersome. Is there a more handy way that would skip creating an extra column? In future I need to sum up cases for red/blue AND for Volume 57/99. Having the extra column appears to make it a bit more tricky.

Also, I didn't manage to get the original colour being taken over if it's not red nor blue. I tried it this way but it woudln't work:

```
df$test = ifelse(df$Colour %in% c("red", "blue"),"red_or_blue",df$Colour)
```

Cheers, Paul

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way sticking in base R (but probably not the most efficient way....)

1. Split your data into groups by `Volume`

   ```
   temp = split(df, df$Volume)
   ```
2. Create a quick function to change the values for "red" and "blue" only in groups where there is a "red" ***AND*** a "blue" present.

   ```
   red.and.blue = function(x) {
     if (sum(c("red", "blue") %in% x$Colour) > 1) {
       x$Colour = gsub("red|blue", "red-and-blue", x$Colour)
     } else {
       x$Colour = as.character(x$Colour)
     }
     x
   }
   ```
3. Use that function on your `temp` object that you created in Step 1:

   ```
   temp = lapply(temp, red.and.blue)
   ```
4. Use `aggregate()` to perform the aggregation you need to do. Specify the names in the `aggregate()` arguments so that you maintain your original column names.

   ```
   temp = lapply(temp, function(x) aggregate(list(Cases = x$Cases), 
                                             list(Colour = x$Colour, 
                                                  Volume = x$Volume), sum))
   ```
5. Put it back all into a `data.frame()`. Don't forget to assign a name if you want to store it as is.

   ```
   do.call(rbind, temp)
   #             Colour Volume Cases
   # 46    red-and-blue     46     9
   # 57.1         green     57     5
   # 57.2  red-and-blue     57     6
   # 57.3        yellow     57     3
   # 99.1         green     99     3
   # 99.2  red-and-blue     99     3
   # 111.1          red    111     2
   # 111.2       yellow    111     4
   # 122           blue    122     1
   ```

Comment: Of course, edit appropriately for "`red-or-blue`" instead of "`red-and-blue`" as I've done here.

Comment: Thanks mrdwab. It works well and its more elegant than my way. Doing it your way how can I also aggregate for volume at the same time, i.e aggregate if colour = red or blue and aggregate if volume = 46 or 57. Doing it my way i simply add a new column. using your way I first create a new formula for volume 46 or 57 but then I need to integrate it in steps 3ff.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you follow @mrdwab's approach, you can use `sapply` on each "split volume" to do

```
df$Cases <- sum(df[(df$Colour =='blue' | df$Colour == 'red'),][,3])
```

to get the number of cases, and

```
df$Colour[(df$Colour =='blue' | df$Colour == 'red')] <- 'readandblue'
```

to change the colornames.  I'm also willing to bet there's a 2-line solution using `ddply` but I'm not an expert w/ that tool (yet).